# yii - how to send validation results to different controller action

Tags: php, yii

I have a CActiveForm in an actionIndex  that posts to actionUpdate. When the model is saved (actionUpdate) I need the validation results (ex: a blank field error message) sent back to ActionIndex to display in the form.

Object is returned, but no validation messages appear if a field is left blank. Rules are set up correctly.

Also for this I am not using ajax.

Here is my code:

```
actionIndex() {
   if isset($_GET("id")) {
       $myformModel =$this->loadModel($_GET("id"));
       $this->render('index',
         array('myformModel' =>    $myformModel);
  }
}

actionUpdate($id){
    $model->attributes = $_POST["myformModel"];
    $model->save();

   //send results back to index. Problem is validation results do not display.
   $this->redirect(array('index','model' => $model);
}
```

My rules in myformModel

```
public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('username, email', 'required','message'=> 'Please fill in blank'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you add your model rules

Comment: Mohan thanks for the reply. I just added it. Please take a look when you get the chance. Thanks

Comment: Initialize the model in update method $model = new modelname() or load the model like $model=$this→loadmodel(variableid);

Comment: When I add loadModel to action Update, I still do not recieve form validation info when the page returns to actionIndex. Isnt it a problem with the redirect not carrying over the validation results?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario one of ways to do this is to use Yii flash messages to keep info from update action to index action after redirection. For example, user submit form to update action, u do all validation and if its fail u get all errors and create flash message (aka one-time session) and redirect to index action. Than in index action u can ask is flash message exist and show it with validation info. 
Issue what i see with this scenario is that u will not have easy option to mark not valid form field, u will only have text message with errors.
From my point of view its much better to use same action for doing both jobs, display form and submit validation. In that case u will check in action if $_POST['ModelName'] is set and if it is you will do validation and save. If validation fail u just need to allow page to load form and it will automatic mark form fields for errors and also display errors summary on top of form.
Here is how it can look with your code:

```
actionIndex() {
 if isset($_GET("id")) {
   $myformModel =$this->loadModel($_GET("id"));

   if (isset($_POST['MyFromModel'])) {
       $myformModel->attributes = $_POST['MyFormModel'];
       if ($myformModel->save()) { // do validation and save in one place
           // everything is good, do something
       }
       // let page load form, if validation is not pass it will automatic show that on    form
   }
   $this->render('index',
     array('myformModel' =>    $myformModel);
  }
}
```